# Can not start smtp in Python

Tags: python, smtp, telnet

I tried to start a smtp server with python with the following code:

```
import smtplib
smtp_server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
```

And I get the following error:

```
File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    smtp_server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 242, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 302, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 277, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
```

I tried to `telnet localhost 25` and `telnet localhost` but they both give the following error:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

The same python code runs perfectly well on one of my other machines.

Any advice ?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

The machine I'm having problem with is running Python 2.7.2, while the machine that the code works well is running Python 2.6.2. I don't know if this is one of the reasons.

Comment: it's a configuration thing of you local smtp server. hard to say more without seeing more details of the configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`smtplib` is SMTP protocol client. What you are looking for is [`smtpd`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtpd.html).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that smtplib does not provide an SMTP server implementation, it implements SMTP client. Most likely, the code tries to connect to localhost and fails. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html

Is the other machine you write about already running an SMTP server?

And what are you trying to do?

Comment: How can I tell whether the machine is running an SMTP server ? And if it's not running, how can start one?

Comment: telnet to SMTP port, for example. Try doing it without running your program. If it succeeds, there already is a server. It is hard to give a reasonable answer, I need to understand what are you trying to do and for what purpose.

Comment: I am trying to start a SMTP server and send email in the end of a program to inform me of the running status. It's working very well on all the other machines.

Comment: Since smtplib is implementation of smtp client, it can not just work on other machines. You are not using smtpd. If it works, it works not in a way you supposed it to work. It just connects to an smtp server on localhost. Probably then you can send an email. If the machine it works on is accessible by network, try specifying it (or its IP) instead of localhost. Creating and setting up an SMTP server usually is not a thing you need just for sending emails.